# add parentheses to natbib year

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to add parentheses to year in natbib references. for example instead of

[1] A. De Ange, "characterization of a practical system,"  Instrumentation
Measurement, vol. 71, pp. 19, 2022.

I want

[1] A. De Ange, "characterization of a practical system,"  Instrumentation
Measurement, vol. 71, pp. 19 (2022).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\biboptions{sort&compress}

\begin{document}
\cite{ref2}

...
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{references}
...
\end{document}
```

and the bib file is

```
    @article{ref2,
  title={characterization of a practical system},
  author={De Ange},
  journal={Instrumentation Measurement},
  volume={71},
  pages={1--9},
  year={2022},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to `TeX.SE`, please post the content of your `.bib` file also (just an entry is enough)

Comment: You want to keep the comma before the parentheses?? Or is it a mistake?

Comment: I need to put the year in parentheses. I don't keep the comma.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are planning to submit to Elsevier or not, but if you are then you should use their own bibliography styles and not the IEEE bibliography style.

Comment: No, we can use other style. It is not IEEE